# Can we have syntax highlighting for Prolog?

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

**Can we please have syntax highlighting for Prolog?**

Ideally, this would include highlighting for built-ins as defined in ISO/IEC 13211-1 and other built-ins if the specific implementation is known (SWI-Prolog and Sicstus Prolog have their own tags, for instance).

Comment: There are a lot of cases where Prolog systems differ, see [this comparison](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/conformity_assessment).